# QUERY join for members that have entries

Tags: query, queries, querystring

I'm trying to learn how to do mysql joins. Twitter has helped already get me started.

I'm trying to find the number of members that have entries attached to them...

Then the number of members that have entries with a specific category_id attached to them.

What I have so far.

```
{exp:query sql="
    SELECT count(*) AS num_members
    FROM exp_members m
    JOIN exp_channel_titles t on t.author = m.member_id"}

    {num_members}

{/exp:query}
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting now? That looks right to me, though I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: Unknown column 't.author' in 'on clause'

Comment: Ok, here is the final code. Makes way more sense now actually seeing code that works the way I wanted it.

Thanks you guys for clearing this up.

    {exp:query sql=" SELECT count(*) AS num_members
                     FROM exp_members m
                     JOIN exp_channel_titles t on t.author_id = m.member_id
                     Where channel_id='4' AND status='Goal_set' "}
    
    {num_members}
    
    {/exp:query}

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't it be t.author_id instead of t.author?

```
{exp:query sql="
    SELECT count(*) AS num_members
    FROM exp_members m
    JOIN exp_channel_titles t on t.author_id = m.member_id"}

    {num_members}

{/exp:query}
```

Comment: Nice catch! I'll edit your answer to add the complete solution.